# Capture specific string and send notification every time

Tags: monitoring, logs

This is a script in bash. [Here](http://sprunge.us/LBjI)

Which capture a string "ERROR: your TCP- connection is dead." 
from a Live dynamic log file. Here the name of a log file "TcpRcpt.log"
which contain sample of a log data below.

---

```
SAT Mar 26 19:55:37  2016 TCPRcpt-0297--ERROR: your TCP- connection is dead.
SAT Mar 26 19:55:37  2016 TCPRcpt-0297--RUNNING
SAT Mar 26 19:55:37  2016 TCPRcpt-0297--RUNNING
SAT Mar 26 19:55:37  2016 TCPRcpt-0298--ERROR: your TCP- connection is dead.
```

Now, issue step 
`logtail TcpRcpt.log | grep -m 1 "ERROR: your TCP- connection is dead." | sed 's/.*TCPRcpt-/ PID /;s/ -//' >> LOGFILE.LOG`

It always gives 0 value, even though it does not capture the string.
Which makes if condition to send notification every time, when loop
execute.

Now my question: Is there any other alternative? which notify via
email when it capture the string every time?

Comment: `grep m 1 "ERROR: your TCP connection is dead."` looks for the string `m` in the files `1` and `"ERROR: your TCP connection is dead."`. for starters.

Comment: Sorry it's -m there

Comment: I tried to fix your formatting, but in doing so I noticed that the log has "TCP-" while your grep does not have a dash

Comment: Also, the capitalization of tcprcpt is different between the log file and the sed

Comment: Yes agree. between it was my mistake, I have corrected it. now check.

Comment: The TCP- still does not match your grep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'It always gives 0 value' because that's the exit code of the last command in the pipeline - sed, which succeed (returns 0) even when no replace happens.

Setting **[pipefail](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html#The-Set-Builtin)** option   will make the result of the pipe set to the result of the first failed command in the pipeline, if any. Modify your script by setting that option before calling logtail  :

```
    ...
    set -o pipefail
    logtail TcpRcpt.log | grep -m 1 "ERROR: your TCP- connection is dead." | sed 's/.*TCPRcpt-/ PID /;s/ -//' >> LOGFILE.LOG
    ...
```